# button with <a> taged hyper link not working in IE

Tags: html, button

just got a weird problem:

code like

```
<div style="margin:20px; text-align:center;">
    <a href="/Deals/Add"><button id="addDeal">Add New Deal</button></a>
</div>
```

no longer works in IE any more, but still working on Firefox, chrome, safari. 
any ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "no longer works" mean? Also, what is the `<a>` around the `<button>` doing?

Comment: Why are you wrapping a button in a link in any case?

Comment: maybe i remembered wrong or mixed up with other browsers, did not use IE much, but problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just:

```
<a href="/Deals/Add">Add New Deal</a>
```

and style it with CSS to look as you like?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `type="button"` to your `button`, as [the default `type` is `submit`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5).

Comment: No, the default `type` is `button`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534696%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Gufa Default `type` [is meant to be `submit`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5). [At least it is in my browser (Firefox 3.6) too](http://jsfiddle.net/PzchY/).